# How to calculate and create new variables and populate new column, grouping by category, in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and would like to do something that I believe should be quite simple but I lack the coding skills.

I have population data for birds as a data frame `birdData`, and for each species `species`, I have population for the county `population_county`, the types of habitat they use `habitat_type` and how much area each habitat encompasses in the county `habitat_area_county`. An example data frame looks like this:

| species | population_county | habitat_type | habitat_area_county |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| thrush | 1000 | woodland | 250 |
| thrush | 1000 | wetland | 370 |
| bluebird | 2000 | open field | 450 |
| bluebird | 2000 | woodland | 320 |

Here are is the order of operations that I am going for:

1. Calculate the ratio of the `habitat_area_county` to total area per species `ratio_habitat`.
2. Use that variable to estimate the population in that habitat type `population_per_habitat_type`.
3. Use these new values for further calculates in a similar fashion.

Ideally these new variables should populate the same data frame so that they are shown as appended columns like so:

| species | population_county | habitat_type | habitat_area_county | ratio_habitat | population_per_habitat_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| thrush | 1000 | woodland | 250 | 0.40 | 400 |
| thrush | 1000 | wetland | 370 | 0.60 | 600 |
| bluebird | 2000 | open field | 450 | 0.58 | 1160 |
| bluebird | 2000 | woodland | 320 | 0.42 | 840 |

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? I cannot find out the way to get your **like so** thing using sample. I think that `ratio_habitat` is ratio of `habitat_area_county` .

```
df %>%
  group_by(habitat_type) %>%
  mutate(ratio_habitat = habitat_area_county/sum(habitat_area_county),
         population_per_habitat = population_county * ratio_habitat)

  species  population_county habitat_type habitat_area_county ratio_habitat population_per_habitat
  <chr>                <int> <chr>                      <int>         <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 thrush                1000 woodland                     250         0.439                   439.
2 thrush                1000 wetland                      370         1                      1000 
3 bluebird              2000 open field                   450         1                      2000 
4 bluebird              2000 woodland                     320         0.561                  1123.
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about the ratio but you're right, it's the ratio between the habitat type area for that species and the sum of the area of the habitat types for that species. What you wrote totally works, except I changed it to be grouped by species and not habitat type. Then the ratios added up correctly. Thank you so much!